# D3.csvParse and D3.csv(filename) not working in Angular

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have a minimal project on plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/QlUEWjsFEbOnBrx8VFhj?p=preview).

I'm trying to figure out how to load data from a csv file into an Angular project that will be using d3.js:

```
let test = "foo,bar\n1,2\n3,4";
let result1 = D3.csvParse(test);
console.log(result1);
let result2 = d3.csvParse(test);
console.log(result2);
let test2 =D3.csv("test.csv");
console.log(test2);
let test3 =d3.csv("test.csv");
console.log(test3);
```

When using a test string instead of loading data using d3.csv (or D3.csv), I also noticed that d3.csvParse (or D3.csvParse) weren't working, either. I'm now thinking something is weird about the way I imported d3?

Any help would be much appreciated. New to Angular, newer to d3, and brand new to Plunker.

Answer (score 1):

Minor mistake: You seem to be using d3 v3 in which parsing is done by `d3.csv.parse`. `d3.csvParse` is a v4 method.

Here's a fork: https://plnkr.co/edit/vJLufI0gigpZZ136NW8X?p=preview